# How do I get the latitude and longitude for each of the points on the embedded google map?

Tags: python, google-maps, web-scraping

The map is on the following website:
http://agora.ex.nii.ac.jp/earthquake/201103-eastjapan/energy/electrical-japan/

The map shows up once it is clicked. Each of the points on the map correspond to a power plant.

If I click on one of the points, more information shows up, such as the plant type, plant name, owner as well as the size of the plant and there is a google map link as well.

By mousing over the google website link on the pop up, I can see that the latitude and longitude coordinates are within the url of the google map link.

My goal is to obtain a table containing plant type, name, owner, size of plant, as well as the latitude and longitude, for all the dots on the map.

I tried looking at the source of the web page but it seems that the extra information only shows up after a point on the map is clicked on.

I can do some python so I would appreciate if someone could point me in the correct direction or general method to go about obtaining the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `requests`/`json` to load the data:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'http://agora.ex.nii.ac.jp/earthquake/201103-eastjapan/energy/electrical-japan/power.json'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data to screen:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for val in data:
    for k, v in val.items():
        print('{:<5} {}'.format(k, v))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
p     8212
u     /earthquake/201103-eastjapan/radiation/speedi/07/
lng   138.594222
o     東京電力株式会社
x     3
lat   37.427361
y     9
c     3
n     柏崎刈羽原子力発電所＜1,2,3,4,5,6,7＞
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c     3
n     鹿島火力発電所＜1,2,3,4,5,6,7コ＞
lat   35.916938
y     9
o     東京電力株式会社
x     1
p     5660
lng   140.701507
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lat   35.342207
y     9
c     3
n     富津火力発電所＜1コ,2コ,3コ,4コ＞
lng   139.832547
p     5160
x     1
o     東京電力株式会社
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and son on.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The solution is perfect!